# How to schedule a sequence number reset in QuickFIX?

Tags: fix, quickfix

What is the recommended way to handle scheduled sequence number resets (initiated by the counterparty once per day) ?

Comment: What do you mean by handle? You don't need to do anything, quickfix handles a seq num reset by itself.

Comment: you may want to backup or move the log and store directories.

Comment: I keep getting error messages when quickfix tries to log in when a counterparty resets a sequence number:  58=MsgSeqNum too low, expecting x but received y

Comment: Good point rupweb !

Answer (score 1):

Sequence Number Reset depends on FIX engine configuration.
If you have FIX initiator you can set "ResetOnLogon=N", so that your acceptor will keep track of sequence number.
In case of sequence number mismatch, both counterparty/FIX engine will replay messages that were lost.

If you have Acceptor at your end, then you can ask counterparty(initiator) FIX engine to keep "ResetOnLogon=N".

Refer this [link](http://www.quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/configuration.html).